# Closing activities stack after a button click

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, I start an eight step "wizard" from my landing page in which data is passed from step 1 all the way to step 8. For keeping the data intact while still in between steps, I am not calling finish() on either of the activities. However, when all the steps are complete, is there a way that I can close all the 8 activities I had started and return back to the landing page?

An illustration of sorts here:

Home - Step 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8

At this point, when the user clicks "Save", close all the Steps (8) and go back to the Home Page. I have been creating a new intent to do this so far, but i realize this is not the best solution. A simple back press takes him back to the 7th Step.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "For keeping data intact while still in between"... Not sure exactly what you mean by this, but keep in mind that you cannot guarantee that one of the activities won't be closed by Android after it is in the background.  Make sure you don't depend on them being there.

Comment: @Mayra: is there anyway I can prevent Android from closing any of the activities? I don't think the steps would take more than a couple of minutes, ideally at least. But you can never be too sure.

Comment: No, you cannot.  Checkout the Activity lifecycle documentation for details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle  You should properly handle stopping and restarting anyways, for the case when someone clicks away from your app and comes back to it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will kill all the activities in between from your 8th screen and launch your hom screen back. also u can set ur home screen's acitivty in manifest launchmode="singleTop". see this link - [developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask)

Comment: Thanks a lot Varun. That worked like a charm. Just what I was looking for. A quick question again. What does setting the Home activity in the manifest with the launchmode="SingleTop" parameter do?

Comment: using the above code will launch a new instance of the Home screen activity. but if u set the launchmode of the home screen as singeTop only one instance of the acitivity will exist and the intent will be delivered to onNewIntent( method of the acitivity.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be to use StartActivityForResult(...) to start each activity, and have activities call setResult() before finish().  Then in each Activity's onActivityResult(...) method call finish() if the intent is non-null.

This will create the full stack, and automatically chain-finish them all when the last finishes.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data == null) {
        return;  // back button, resume this activity
    }

    // Propagate result down the stack.
    setResult(0, data);
    finish();
}
```

This gives you a little more control and lets the original activity receive the result via onActivityResult rather than the create intent, which might be more intuitive if the original request has other state you want to preserve (in its start intent, in particular).

Comment: Under my circumstances, this wont work. I can already see where I can use your solution. But in this case, the steps I mentioned are more like a form collecting information and the content is only passed in one direction. Nothing is sent back. Varun's solution is the one in my case. Thanks for the help nonetheless. Will certainly use it in a different situation.