# How to finish an activity and return to a varied location?

Tags: android, back-stack

My application implements an action which stretch upon 3-4 activities.
the entry point to this process can be from different activities in the application. (HomeActivity, various displayActivities). I want to return to the starting activity once the last activity is finished successfully.

Is there a best practice way to do it? thankyou.

Comment: You just want to create an Intent to open either a specific activity, or you can pass around an Intent extra to identify the 'home' activity. Basic tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: See if this question of mine from way back helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348839/closing-activities-stack-after-a-button-click. They seems pretty similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global static boolean to help you with this (in the example `SomeClass.IsClosingFlow`),
 Plus, you should define each activity to "mark" if it's in the "flow" (flow=meaning it's part of the pack of activities that need to be closed). I recommend using this mark as an abstract method if you all your activities are extending some abstract-activity (i.e. `isActivityInFlow()`).

The following code demonstrates this,
It needs to be places in `onResume()` of each activity in the application:

```
    // Check to see if we are in the process of closing activities
    if (SomeClass.IsClosingFlow){
        if (isActivityInFlow()){
            this.finish();  
        }
        else{
            // If we got here, and we're not in the flow anymore
            SomeClass.IsClosingFlow = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of different ways to manage this kind of application flow. One way that may work for you and is pretty easy is to just use `startActivityForResult()` when you call from one activity to the next. Then, when you are finally done, you just set the result and call `finish()`. In each activity you can then implement `onActivityResult()` so that it sets the result and calls `finish()` on itself. In this way you can chain forward a number of activities and then chain back to whoever started the chain.