# Finish All Instance of particular Activity

Tags: android, instance, activity-finish, activity-stack

There can be many activities in application and the last launched activity stay on top of stack and on pressing back it finish the current activity.I have a sequence of Activity and here is the flow ..

if we have A,B,**C(1)**,D,**C(2)**... Activity C(1) and C(2) are two different instance of Activity C launched while navigating the application .So what is requisite is to clear all the instance of activity C and the result should be when I finish **C(2)** I should have left with these stack **A,B,D**. What should I do .

**IMP** -I want to keep the **C(1)** alive in stack until unless I finish the C(2)
as  I  could have started C with New Task flag rather than creating these instances , but these instance have different UI and work .

The following approaches are not favorable .

**First**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(C(2).this , D.class);    
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will clear All the activity from Stack and relaunch Activity

**Second**

Keep the track of Activity in singleton class and then relaunching the required flow, how ever this will consume the time when there are many Activities to be started .

So I thought that there should be some solution using package manager or other that will resolve the problem , solution are appreciated

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to close activity C1 manually when finishing activity C2.

However you can take care of activity C1 in it's on resume this way -

1 - Set a flag in your application class :

```
public static boolean IsClosingActivities = false;
```

This value can be set "true" by C2 right before "finish" of activity C2 occurs.

And set "false" in the point where you'll call startActivity for a new activity C. (Assuming that new instances of activity C can be created later in the application).

2 - In C implementation of on resume :

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();
        if (YourApplication.IsClosingActivities) {
                this.finish();
        } 
    }
```

This way - when the user navigates back from D - C1 will finish itself and he will be navigated to B.

Comment: I've had similar situation, and doing it manually was the only way I found. You can see the answer in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499034/how-to-finish-an-activity-and-return-to-a-varied-location - accept the answer if it works for you :)