# Kill all instances of an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm setting up Notifications in my app and I've noticed whilst testing, after clicking a new notifications (in this case the notification loads a blog details page), I have many instances of the blog details activity running (pressing back it shows each activity with the previously loaded blogs).

Is it possible in my Receiver class, so look if there is any instance of `ActivityBlog` already running, and if there all `.finish()` them all so there is only ever once instance running?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766929/finish-all-instance-of-particular-activity) but I couldn't work out a way to do it from that.

Comment: Why don't you use `singleInstance` as launch mode for this activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should study *activity launch modes* 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Use **android:launchMode="singleTop"** in  element in manifest file.
You will get callback in **onNewIntent()** if an instance of activity is already up. Stack of your activities will be automatically updated and there wont be any need of killing activities which is consumes time and resources.
This i believe is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Intent z = new Intent(Projects_Accel.this,MainActivity.class);
    z.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    startActivity(z);
```

use this for kill all activity

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityBlog.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
activity.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

**NOTE:**

You need to put **android-support.jar** in **libs** folder